# PHP Group By value - JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, split, dropdown

I have this JSON data:

```
"slots": [
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:00:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 08:20:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:20:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 08:40:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:40:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 09:00:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 08:40:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:00:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 09:00:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:20:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 09:20:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:40:00"
      }
```

I would like to split dateTime "start" to $date and $time. It work with this:

```
echo '<select name="reservationDate" id="test">';
            foreach($slots_start as $option){
                $dateTime = $option->start;
                list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $dateTime);
                echo '<option value=' . $date. '>' . $date . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

With the above code I see the dropdown list with all values splitted by $date.

Now I want to group by $date and then show $time grouped in another select dropdown.

See Scheme:
[image scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkSW0.jpg)

Comment: you'll have to make an array, where the key is $date, and the value is an array of $time, first...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to create javascript array with php.

https://jsfiddle.net/bruvygjf/

```
<?php
$json_str =<<<EOF
[
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:00:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 08:20:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:20:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 08:40:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-09 08:40:00",
        "end": "2017-02-09 09:00:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 08:40:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:00:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 09:00:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:20:00"
      },
      {
        "start": "2017-02-10 09:20:00",
        "end": "2017-02-10 09:40:00"
      }
]
EOF;
$slots = json_decode($json_str);

$times = array();

foreach($slots as $option){
    list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $option->start);

    if (!array_key_exists($date, $times)){
        $times[$date] = array();
    }

    if (!in_array($time, $times[$date])){
        $times[$date][] = $time;
    }
}

echo '<select name="reservationDate" id="firstSelect" onchange="fillSecond()">';

foreach (array_keys($times) as $date){
    echo '
    <option value="' . $date. '">' . $date . '</option>';   
}
echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="reservationTime" id="secondSelect"></select>';
?>

<script language="javascript">
function fillSecond(){
    firstSelectElement = document.getElementById('firstSelect');
    secondSelectElement = document.getElementById('secondSelect');
    times = date_options[firstSelectElement.selectedIndex];

    while (secondSelectElement.options.length > 0) {                
        secondSelectElement.remove(0);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        var new_option = document.createElement('option');
        new_option.innerHTML = times[i];
        new_option.value = times[i];
        secondSelectElement.appendChild(new_option);
    }
}

date_options = [];
<?php
foreach($times as $date => $times){
    echo "date_options.push([]);";
    foreach ($times as $time){
        echo "date_options[date_options.length - 1].push('$time');";
    }
}
?>

fillSecond();
</script>
```

Comment: It's definitely not a good practice to output JS code from PHP.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much!! It works if I open the page containing the code.

I have this error if called by ajax production from another php page:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: It depends if you have small amount of data. The PHP is used to output HTML, so I don't see any problem using PHP if you filter input & escape output. You can always use Ajax in production.

Comment: Hi Leon, the Ajax approach would be different. Feel free to post your code that you face with problem.

Comment: Hi Leon, for the Ajax approach, use json_encode() php function to return $times[$_POST['reservationDate']] value. (don't forget to filter POST value first.) Then run javascript code to fill second select element (using the returned JSON encoded string) in front page instead of requested page. Hope this helps to understand the logic.

Comment: Hi Jetblack, thank you so much for the reply.
I'm trying as you told me but I do not understand the kind of approach to use. The javascript of the requested page should be pasted on the first page php?

Comment: When the user change the value of the first select element, you'll need to make ajax call posting the value of the selected element. (it's "date".) On the PHP page that you're calling, you'll need to create an array for the second select element. For that, you'll use the posted date value. Once you create that array, you'll should echo the json encoded string using json_encode. Then on the page where the user changes the first select element, you'll run the javascript code to fill second select element using the returned JSON array(you'll run this code "complete" handler of your ajax call).

Comment: I'm tried everything but doesn't work. Can you help me post example please?

Comment: Hi jetblack,
I'm tried but i get same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I think you need to open up a new question with your code you're facing with a problem since your original question has been already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could group your data first, and then populate both dropdowns.

```
<?php

// group data
$grouped = [];
foreach($slots_start as $option){
  $dateTime = $option->start;
  list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $dateTime);
  if (isset($grouped[$date])) {
     $grouped[$date][] = $time;
  } else {
     $grouped[$date] = [$time];
  }
}
```

Then output both dropdowns.

You can get the dates array with

```
$dates = array_keys($grouped);
```

And every time related to that date with:

```
$times = $grouped[$date];
```

That way you will get much more mantainable code.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying your solution. How I can fill second dropdown? 



`$dates = array_keys($grouped);
  $times = $grouped[$date];

  echo '<select name="reservationDate" id="test">';
        foreach($dates as $optionz){
            echo '<option value=' . $optionz. '>' . $optionz . '</option>';
        }`

Comment: You could loop the grouped array, and loop inside every element to build the second dropdown. Anyway i think that you actually need an ajax approach to solve this problem, not just group the array.

Comment: `if (isset($grouped[$date])) {
     $grouped[$date][] = $time;
  } else {
     $grouped[$date] = [$time];
  }` can be completely replaced by `$grouped[$date][] = $time;`

Answer (score 0):

php with:

```
<select name="company" id="select_company">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Italy</option>
</select>
<select name="reservationDate" id="firstSelect">
        <option>Seleziona date</option>
</select>


//ajax
    $('#select_company').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        $.ajax({
            url: 'my_page.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#firstSelect').hide(function(){
                $('#firstSelect').show().html(data);
            });
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('Errore nel caricamento');    
        });
    });
```

And my_page.php with:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST))
        {
...//my code for get json array
        $times = array();

                    foreach($slots_start as $option){
                        list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $option->start);

                        if (!array_key_exists($date, $times)){
                            $times[$date] = array();
                        }

                        if (!in_array($time, $times[$date])){
                            $times[$date][] = $time;
                        }
                    }

                    echo '<select name="reservationDate" id="firstSelect" onchange="fillSecond()">';

                    foreach (array_keys($times) as $date){
                        echo '
                        <option value="' . $date. '">' . $date . '</option>';   
                    }
                    echo '</select>';

                    echo '<select name="reservationTime" id="secondSelect"></select>';

                    ?>

                    <script language="javascript">
                    function fillSecond(){
                        firstSelectElement = document.getElementById('firstSelect');
                        secondSelectElement = document.getElementById('secondSelect');
                        times = date_options[firstSelectElement.selectedIndex];

                        while (secondSelectElement.options.length > 0) {                
                            secondSelectElement.remove(0);
                        }

                        for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
                            var new_option = document.createElement('option');
                            new_option.innerHTML = times[i];
                            new_option.value = times[i];
                            secondSelectElement.appendChild(new_option);
                        }
                    }

                    date_options = [];
                    <?php
                    foreach($times as $date => $times){
                        echo "date_options.push([]);";
                        foreach ($times as $time){
                            echo "date_options[date_options.length - 1].push('$time');";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    fillSecond();
                    </script>
                    <?php

            }?>
```