# Ajax approach, PHP Post and JSON array CURL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried everything but I can not figure it out.
This is old discussion: [PHP Group By value - JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115127/php-group-by-value-json)

In this other thread I was told that the ajax approach is different. I tried to run their advice but when I write the code Javascript in ajaxData.php file seems not to work.

I need to populate reservationTime dropdown with time array (splitted in ajaxData) and dependent by reservationDate (grouped Date Array).

The code below works and fills reservationDate dropdown with date(splitted). Now I would like populate second dropdown.

[Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXXEF.png)

[reservationDate Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lI28.png)

I have index.php with:

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="a-row">
        <div id="input-parent">
            <select name="company" required="" id="company">
                <option value="">Select company</option>
                <option value="1">Rome</option>
                <option value="2">New York</option>
                <option value="3">Madrid</option>
                <option value="4">Tokyo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="input-parent">
            <select name="productCode" required="" id="product">
                <option value="">Select product</option>
                <option value="IPAD">iPad</option>
                <option value="GALAXY">Samsung Galaxy</option>
                <option value="LGTV">LG TV</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="input-parent">
            <select name="reservationDate" required="" id="date">
                <option>Select date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="input-parent">
            <select name="reservationTime" required="" id="time">
                <option>Select time</option>
            </select>
        </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="a-row">
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize() // serializzo
        })
        .done(function(data){
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('Error'); 
        });
    });

    // Company change
    $('#company').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        var productID = $("select#product option:checked" ).val();
        var companyID = $(this).val();
        if(companyID && productID != ""){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:{company:companyID,productCode:productID},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#firstSelect').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            console.log("Nothing");
        }
    });

    // Product change
    $('#product').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        var companyID = $("select#company option:checked" ).val();
        var productID = $(this).val();
        if(companyID && productID != ""){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:{company:companyID,productCode:productID},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#firstSelect').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            console.log("Nothing");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And ajaxData.php where I split date and time and insert loop date values into date dropdown of index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["company"]) && isset($_POST["productCode"]))
    {
        // Token ID
        $authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        // To send API
        $companyData = $_POST["company"];
        $productData = $_POST["productCode"];

        // Setup cURL
        $ch = curl_init('https://.../'.$companyData.'/'.$productData.'' );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Aythorization: '.$authToken,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        // Send Request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Response
        $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        $responseData = json_decode($response);

        // Setup Var
        $availableSlots = $responseData->availableSlots;
        $slots_start = $responseData->availableSlots->slots;

        // Check if errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            die;
        }


            $times = array();

            foreach($slots_start as $option){
                list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $option->start);

                if (!array_key_exists($date, $times)){
                    $times[$date] = array();
                }

                if (!in_array($time, $times[$date])){
                    $times[$date][] = $time;
                }
            }

            foreach ($slots_start as $option){
                echo '
                <option value="' . $option->start. '">' . $option->start . '</option>';   
            }
    }
?>
```

My JSON data:

```
{
   "response":    {
      "storeTimeZone": "Europe/Paris",
      "slots":       [
         {
            "start": "2017-01-23T08:00:00Z"
         },
                  {
            "start": "2017-01-23T08:20:00Z"
         },
                  {
            "start": "2017-01-23T08:40:00Z"
         },
                  {
            "start": "2017-01-16T08:00:00Z"
         },
                  {
            "start": "2017-01-16T08:20:00Z"
         },
                  {
            "start": "2017-01-16T08:40:00Z"
         }
...
```

Comment: Really not clear what your specific problem is

Comment: "I need to populate reservationTime dropdown with time"